# Adjective for "wide" space?

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

I'm trying to translate something from Japanese. The original is talking about a store that is very "wide", i.e., its sideways dimensions are disproportionately long. You could think of it as a place that has an enormous storefront, but doesn't go nearly as deep inside as you'd expect.

I can't however think of any suitable adjective to place in the attributive position for the noun (store), because somehow "wide store" doesn't sound right, and neither do all the other synonyms that I've tried.

Is there a good adjective with this meaning, or do I have no choice but to rearrange the sentence? In that case, how should I express this idea?

Using "wide" predicatively ("the store is wide") sounds a bit better but I'm still not totally sure about it. I thought I could say "expansive", but that doesn't quite convey the idea that it's only the width that is unusual, not both the length and the width.

I'd appreciate your opinions on this.

Comment: *Broad*, though a synonym of *wide*, may suit better here.

Comment: ***Spacious***: having a large capacity or area. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spacious

Comment: *Spacious* is exactly what is being **avoided** here.

Comment: *Wide frontage* may be clearer, for that matter.

Comment: So, "wide" by itself is unsatisfactory because it fails to convey that the store's width stands in contrast to its depth. Unfortunately with translation work you can't get too creative, or else you might try a compound adjective... it's a shallow-but-freakishly-wide store.

Comment: I would use "open", assuming that the store plan was indeed "open".

Answer (score 1):

**wide** 
is okay to describe a store. However, if you are trying to convey the idea that it is wide relative to its depth, you could say

**wide but shallow store**

Or

**wide, shallow store**

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is **sprawling** from sprawl: "to be stretched or spread out in an unnatural or ungraceful manner".

Answer (score 0):

The store is wide, or the store was wide depending on what tense you are doing it in. Wide is  an adjective, you can't really describe an adjective although you can use synonyms to give the reader a better picture in their head of what it is. Maybe you should use two scentences to describe the store.

Answer (score 0):

The sore was **deceptively** wide. It shows that it is wide enough to be deep, but isn't.

Comment: "Deceptively wide" means that it is wide while not appearing to be so - nothing about depth.

Answer (score 0):

"**Broad but shallow** store".

Or "the store was broad but shallow".

Answer (score 0):

The word is *Storefront*.

A store is defined by the size of its *storefront*. The *breadth* of the storefront means the width a store takes up along the walkway, or street, where it is seen. This dimension means the difference between dealing with just your local buddies and serving the approaching masses. Businesses live and die by the storefront they can represent.

The balance the proprietor must decide upon is the square feet needed to complete his work versus the price he could get for the remaining space.